# Method to refresh PNG file without refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Created a captcha using imagestring

```
 imagestring($image, 5,  5, 30, $text, $text_color);
 imagepng($image,"captcha_image.png"); 
 imagepng($image,"captcha_image.png");
```

above is part of the code only.

```
  <img src="captcha_image.png" id="captchaimage"/>
```

above code is my html code

> How do I able to refresh my PNG file ( captcha + session thingy ) without pressing F5

Comment: JavaScript or Ajax is probably what you need. It's impossible with only php

Comment: if you use JavaScript to change the src attribute of the image then the browser should attempt to reload it

Comment: Thanks for the response , as  any diea on javascript ? I have tried on document.getElementById('captchaimage').src+ '?' +new Date(); but no luck

Comment: @VoxVola share what you've tried with javascript

Comment: Are you trying to make a captche image? If so address the question better for a more definite answer

Comment: @BobbyAxe yes , trying to make captcha , but captcha i already done it , now i trying to make a "refresh captcha"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally i won't write this much code as stackoverflow isn't a coding service but after seeing screenshots of your code in the comments am convinced you have made a fair attempt but in the wrong direction hence the following piece of code is an example guide line of how a captche code should be using PHP and AJAX.

This first file is the image file it is named **captche_image.php** and should be separate as ajax calls will be made to it:

```
<?php

session_start();

function captche_generator()
{
    function ct_rand($lenght=6)
    {
        $characters = '0123456789'; $tumble="";
        for ($i=0; $i < $lenght ; $i++) {$tumble .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];} return $tumble;
    }

    //font file, font size, image text and save text to session
    $fontfile   ='../fonts/JustMeAgainDownHere.ttf';
    $fontsize   =50;
    $text       =ct_rand();
    $_SESSION['captche'] = $text;

    //image size, backgroundcolor, transparent background, textcolor
    $captche_image = imagecreate(180, 50);
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($captche_image, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($captche_image, $background_color);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($captche_image, 0, 0, 0);

    //a loop to create scrambled line in image
    for ($xy=0; $xy <=50 ; $xy++)
    { 
        $x1= rand(1,1000);
        $y1= rand(1,1000);
        $x2= rand(1,100);
        $y2= rand(1,100);
        imageline($captche_image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $text_color);
    }

    //create image in .png extension
    imagettftext($captche_image, $fontsize, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, $fontfile, $text);
    imagepng($captche_image);

    //set header and return created image
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    return $captche_image;
}

captche_generator();

?>
```

This other file should be your captche page it a combined page of PHP and HTML and i have added minimal CSS to make it visible.

```
    <?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if(isset($_GET["captche_input"]) && filter_var($_GET["captche_input"], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
{
    if($_SESSION['captche'] === $_GET["captche_input"])
    {
        session_destroy();
        ob_flush();
        header("location:./login.php"); //redirect to the login page or any other page you wish
    }
    else
    {
        session_destroy();
        ob_flush();
        echo "<center><p style='padding: 5px;background-color:red;'> Code is Incorrect. Please try Again.</p></center>";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Code is Incorrect. Please try Again.'); </script>";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    body{
    background-image: url("../images/captche_bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-position: right;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    .captcheBoard{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .captcheBack{
    position: relative;
    height: 90px;
    width: 272px;
    background-image: url('../images/captche_mini.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: center;
    -moz-background-size: center;
    -o-background-size: center;
    background-position: center;
    border: 0.10em solid coral;
    border-radius: 0.03em;
    }
    .captcheFront{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 8%;
    }
    .captcheInputBar{
    position: relative;
    margin: 3% 0%;
    border: 0.10em solid coral;
    border-radius: 0.03em;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    }  
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container captcheBoard">

        <div class="captcheBack">
            <div class="captcheFront"><!--captche image is shown here--></div>
        </div>

        <form action="" method="GET">
            <input type="number" class="captcheInputBar" required name="captche_input" pattern="[0-9]{0,}" placeholder="Enter Captche Here" />
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="Button" name="captche_check" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <input type="button" class="Button" name="captche_refresh" value="Refresh" onclick="reload_captche()"/>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function reload_captche()
        {
            var xhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

            xhttp.open("POST", "./captche_image.php", true);
            xhttp.send();

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("captcheFront")[0].innerHTML = '<img src="./captche_image.php" />';
                }
            }
        }

        window.load = reload_captche();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: The page which the user is been redirected to on success of captche should have a way of verifying that the captche was entered correctly else user can just redirect herself to said page.

Comment: hello , thanks for taking time writing the code , http://prntscr.com/kz7yyo i have implement the code on my website , but somehow it appeared broken ,http://prntscr.com/kz7z7c < i also included some code to take font 'Arial.ttf' , any idea where could do wrong ?

Comment: Note that : for the refresh button is not seen in the image ( due to currently is trying to implement the captcha first ) if it work only implement the refresh button.

Comment: for the background-image i added and not working also .

Comment: You have to specify your own font file, the images replace with your own image location

Comment: See updated code; corrected the style tags that was shown originally as script tags

Comment: Thank you , able to change the refresh now !

Answer (score 2):

As LPK pointed out, you have to change the source of the image via JavaScript in order for the browser to refresh it.

I'm not sure why you were having problems with it, as you indicated in the comments of LPK's answer but maybe you forgot to include the `onclick` property in the HTML.

Here is an example with a snippet that shows how to do it on a timer, on image click, and on an anchor element being clicked. Also as pointed out in LPK's answer, just set the `src` attribute to the same thing to reload the same image.

```js
const captchaImage = document.getElementById('captchaimage');

// Change the captcha image after 1 second.
setTimeout(() => {

  captchaImage.src = 'http://placehold.it/125x125';
  
}, 1000);

// Change it on click.
captchaImage.onclick = () => {

  captchaImage.src = 'http://placehold.it/200x200';
  
};

// Change it when another button clicked.
const testBtn = document.getElementById('testBtn');

testBtn.onclick = () => {

  captchaImage.src = 'http://placehold.it/150x150';
  
};
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" id="captchaimage"/>

<a id='testBtn'>Click to change captcha image</a>
```

For another source on the topic check out this link to the [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp) page and you can check out the 'Try it Yourself' link to see yet another example of this in action.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kz6m2n  ( < this is the html code )  http://prntscr.com/kz6m80 (< my javascript code ) , but after i run it , the button is clickable , but does not change anything .. as the image src of my file is created inside my file ( generated )

Answer (score 1):

Simple things :

```
<img src="yoursource" id="captchaimage" onclick="actualiser()"/>
```

Then :

```
function actualiser() {
document.getElementById("captchaimage").src="yoursource"}
```

So when you click on the image, it'll reload only the image (add the same source to always reload the same image)

**EDIT**

If you don't want to have to click, you can also set a timer that will reload every x seconds (need an other line of code)

Comment: Hello , thanks for the code , but after inserting , the image is unclickable .

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function actualiser() {
    document.getElementById("captchaimage").src="captcha_image.png"}
</script>  @LPK , this is the code