# Javascript , refreshing created png file with session

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, refresh

Created a captcha using imagestring

```
 imagestring($image, 5,  5, 30, $text, $text_color);
 imagepng($image,"captcha_image.png"); 
 imagepng($image,"captcha_image.png");
```

above is part of the code only.

```
  <img src="captcha_image.png" id="captchaimage"/>
```

above code is my html code

> How do I able to refresh my PNG file ( captcha + session thingy ) without pressing F5
>
> **Note:** The PNG file is my attempted to create my own captcha ( not using plugin , and it WORKS , now just trying to add a refresh for my png that also refresh the session of the captcha

Code that i tried:

```
<img src="captcha_image.png" id="captchaimage" onclick="actualiser()"/>
Then :

function actualiser() {
document.getElementById("captchaimage").src="captcha_image.png"}
```

But failed to refresh ( not refreshing - no respond )
**Note that : my image is on .png , not .php**

Comment: Isn't this just another repost of [Method to refresh PNG file without refreshing the whole page](//stackoverflow.com/q/52522056)? How is anyone supposed to know how you use the session when none of your snippets contains any trace thereof?

Comment: i was reported that i lack of information , and needed to add infomation on it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method to refresh PNG file without refreshing the whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522056/method-to-refresh-png-file-without-refreshing-the-whole-page)