# re-trigger php code that already run when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, generate

Is it possible that button onclick triggers an event that already happened?

What does it mean?

I have created a captcha generator. Whenever you refresh/run the page. It will generate a captchaimage.php on the folder. I want that on button onclick. I wanted to re-run the code that is able to generate a new captchaimage.php (for refresh captcha purpose).

The code is on php tag, button of the file.

Comment: PHP runs on the server side of your application while the click of a button is a client side operation. To connect the two you can use ajax, if you don't want to leave the page, using for example a sort of token to trigger the creation only in some case. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did not try on this yet , as i keep on trying on other aspect but found out is my coding fault , and trying a new ways to fix it

Comment: An even better solution is to separate the php function that generate the image in a different php file. So when you click the button you can send an ajax request to the php page that generate the image and you are done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method to refresh PNG file without refreshing the whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522056/method-to-refresh-png-file-without-refreshing-the-whole-page)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ajax, check out jQuery Ajax for details. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/.

Your front end jQuery code can be like this:

```
$.get("http://domain/path/your.php", function(data) {
    // render the page with information received from "data" here
});
```

Your back end php code can do whatever you want to do and in the end "echo $json_result". $json_result could have any information pass to the font end jQuery callback function above.